# Fitting text to a physical size (standard 8.5" x 11" letter paper) in Java

Tags: java, swing, printing

Java has a nice class for dealing with text sizes on a display (FontMetrics) but I can't find anything on how to get the size of a given string of text on a physical piece of paper.

Basically, I have a JTextArea in which the user can enter however much text he/she wishes. I need to figure out how wide a given section of text is on physical paper so that I can insert line breaks.

I would loop through all the text in the text box, adding line breaks if words would end up outside the bounds of the page.

It sounds so simple, but without any way to measure how big the text is, it seems quite difficult. How can I measure how large the text is when printed on paper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the text is it size in pixels divided by the PPI/DPI(pixels/dots per inch) the text will be printed at.
Formula Pixels/DPI=Inches